# Update 2 Redux Store properties with 1 dispatch action/reducer call? (React-Redux)

Tags: redux, react-redux, action, dispatch

**ACTION**

```
export const selectedCourseCard = (courseID) => {
    
    return {

        type: 'UPDATE_SELECTED_COURSE_CARD', 
        selectedTab: 'lecture',
        selectedCourse: courseID,

    }
    
};
```

New to Redux, but trying something relatively simple.  During a button onClick, I want to dispatch an action to update 2 variables in the Redux store.  ("selectedTab" and "selectedCourse").

However, with my current code, "selectedTab" remains the same as before (it doesn't update to 'lectures', as I am trying to explicity do in the ACTION), and "selectedCourse" displays an object rather than updating the "selectedCourse" value with the "courseID" as can be found in the ACTION.

Any clarity on what/how I can achieve the desired action would be greatly appreciated :)

**REDUCER**

```
const initState = '';

const selectedCourseCardReducer = (state=initState, action) => {
    
    switch (action.type) {
        
        case 'UPDATE_SELECTED_COURSE_CARD':

            return {
                selectedTab: action.selectedTab,
                selectedCourse: action.selectedCourse,
            }

        default:

            return state;  
    }
    
}

export default selectedCourseCardReducer
```

Comment: Your code looks ok...there must be something else going on.  Where are you calling your `selectedCourseCard ` action, and what are you passing as the argument for  `courseID`?  Are you inadvertently calling some other action that is overwriting your store state?  You should consider retuning `{ ...state, selectedTab: action.selectedTab, selectedCourse: action.selectedCourse }` from your reducer. inlcuding `...state` in your reducer return statements will help avoid overwtiting the state completely

Comment: Thanks for your response Seth.  I ended up adjusting some things.  (instead of trying to update 2 or 3 seperate Store variables, I combined the variables inside 1 object and update the object as needed.) Thanks again :)